# Use GDI+ with C# to create an image for a site

Tags: c#, fonts, gdi+, embedded-fonts

I'd like to use GDI to generate text images with my fonts on a server to be served on my site.

I want to use any font on my sites, but of course couldn't use any font on a web site... so I guess I'd need to generate images of the text myself.

Ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    using( Font f = new Font( "Times New Roman", 22f ) )
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = CreateImage( "TEXT", pictureBox1.Size, f, Color.Black );
    }
}

Bitmap CreateImage( string text, Size imageSize, Font font, Color fontColor )
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap( imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height );
    using( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( image ) )
    using( Brush brush = new SolidBrush( fontColor ) )
    {
        g.DrawString( text, font, brush, new PointF( 0, 0 ) );
    }

    return image;
}
```

That will simply create an image with some text of a certain size and assign it to a picturebox.  You would of course need to add functionality for setting alignment and things of that nature, but this is the basic idea.  Create an image, get a Graphics object from it, and draw a string.

You can also obtain the width and height of a drawn string using some font 'f' by using the Graphics.MeasureString method.

Comment: Well, that's probably a good idea if this image is going to be served to multiple clients.

Answer (score 2):

Code sample with hard-coding for clarity:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(200, 100);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
    g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.DrawString("Hello World!", new Font("Tahoma", 12), Brushes.DarkBlue, 0, 0);
    b.Save("c:\\MyPic.bmp");
}
```

The picture size (200x100), text, font and starting location (0,0) and destination path are all hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks for the nod and the upvote, but i'm mortar-boarded.  X-|